# data type mismatch while converting into json in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `dataframe` like below. Blank spaces suggests no value is present

```
+---+---+----+---+---+
| a1| b1|  c1| d1| e1|
+---+---+----+---+---+
|  1|  a|foo1|  4|  5|
|   |  b| bar|  4|  6|
|   |  c| mnc|   |  7|
+---+---+----+---+---+
```

```
//Schema

root
 |-- a1: long (nullable = true)
 |-- b1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- c1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- d1: long (nullable = true)
 |-- e1: long (nullable = true)
```

I want to convert it into a row by row json format
so ididsomething like

```
 result = df.withColumn( "JSON",to_json(struct([when (df[x].isNotNull(),df[x]).otherwise(F.lit(None)).alias(x)for x in df.columns])))
```

the results are like

```
{"a1":1,"b1":"a","c1":"foo1","d1":4,"e1":5}
{"b1":"b","c1":"bar","d1":4,"e1":6} 
{"b1":"c","c1":"mnc","e1":6}
```

So the null value columns are not being added in the json structure.

One way to overcome is like instead of F.lit(None) if I add F.lit("") like below

```
result = data.withColumn( "JSON",to_json(struct([when (data[x].isNotNull(),data[x]).otherwise(F.lit("")).alias(x)for x in data.columns])))
```

but adding F.lit("") is converting everything into string.

So I am getting results like

```
{"a1":"1","b1":"a","c1":"foo1","d1":"4","e1":"5"}
{"a1":"",b1":"b","c1":"bar","d1":"4","e1":"6"} 
{"a1":"","b1":"c","c1":"mnc","d1":"","e1":"6"}
```

Can you please suggest a way to overcome this.Like is there any way to cast every column into it's original type?

Comment: no you can't untill and unless you have any default value for `""` empty string while casting to int.

Comment: convert all empty column values something like ```N/A``` (some distinct value) .. because to_json will remove empty column in final result and in final result replace ```N/A``` value with ""

Comment: you can have a default value as -1 for int columns

Comment: what is your spark version?

Comment: @jxc I am using spark-2.3